# Trouble displaying signed unsigned bytes with python

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, byte, frames

I have a weird problem! I made a client / server Python code with Bluetooth in series, to send and receive byte frames (for example: `[0x73, 0x87, 0x02 ....]` )

Everything works, the send reception works very well !

The problem is the display of my frames, I noticed that the bytes from `0` to `127` are displayed, but from `128`, it displays the byte but it adds a `C2` (`194`) behind, for example: `[0x73, 0x7F, 0x87, 0x02, 0x80 ....]` == `[115, 127, 135, 2, 128 ....]` in hex display I would have `73 7F C2 87 2 C2 80 ..` , we will notice that he adds a byte `C2` from nowhere!

I think that since it is from `128`! that it is due to a problem of signed (`-128` to `127`) / unsigned (`0` to `255`).

Anyone have any indication of this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

0xc2 and 0xc3 are byte values that appear when encoding character values between U+0080 and U+00FF as UTF-8. Something on the transmission side is trying to send text instead of bytes, and something in the middle is (*properly*) converting the text to UTF-8 bytes before sending. The fix is to send bytes instead of text in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, actually, under Python3, I made sock.send (chr (frame)) and normally it should yell because chr (i) is a "str" while shipped "bytes". And if he does not moan, it is that he turns it into utf-8: suddenly I change my code by doing sock.send (bytes (frame))